# Every page on chrome says "Page Unresponsive"

Tags: google-chrome

Recently my computer crashed saying something about the graphics while I was playing a game with chrome open in the background. Upon restart I decided that I would just watch YouTube the rest of the night. While I was watching, the FlashPlayer screen in which YouTube displays it videos started to flash with vertical lines of color that appeared to be somewhere in the video, couldn't tell if it was the top or the bottom. Suddenly the screen instead of flashing, this time the vertical bars hold and

the power turns of as if someone pulled the plug. (If this was a desktop...) This is when I noticed that the computer was over heating so I let it sit and fan out all the air till the next afternoon, where I started it back up and started chrome. Though this time the first thing that happens is all of my extensions crash, next the new tab page informs me "Page Unresponsive" and after another min displays the "Aww snap" page. This is happening for all pages and uninstalling and reinstalling chrome did not seam to help at all.

Win 10 Enterprise 64bit (Recently installed)

- GeForce GTX 765M (Updated Drives Today)
- Killer Wireless-N Network Card
- Chrome (Most Recent Release)

No crash logs because chrome is not really "Crashing" in its standers.

If any other information is required please let me know what it is and how I get it and I will come back to you with it.

Comment: Any chance you caught the actual temperatures from the supposed overheating incident?

Comment: Sorry @jatuttle0 , I didn't I have a Alienware 14 laptop and I was able to feel the heat coming through the keyboard. I don't know if that helps any. All of the other programs seam to run fine, I'm using the Edge browser to respond right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really know what happened but after a while it seamed to fix it's self.